# How to create GIF in Flash, from specific points inside the timeline?

Tags: flash, gif, banner, timeline

I made a lot of banners that have 3 different content groups that continually fade in and out, using Alpha (transparency) on Movie Clips. Please note I have many movie clips that fade in and out, not 1 per each fade in/out.

I need to make GIF versions of all these banners... Without alpha fade in and out, just 3 pictures changing every 3 seconds. How do i create these "pictures" without Print Screen? How do I take a snapshot from specific points in the timeline? And please note I have A LOT of these banners, and not a lot of time.

If this involves using AS please be specific because I don't have vast knowledge in that field unfortunately...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Within Flash, you can choose File - Export - Export Movie - format Animated GIF. I think the fastest way for you to do it without the alpha fades would be to just drag those 100% opacity key frames into a new layer that has the animation you want for GIF before exporting the animation. 
You could also try File- Export - Image, to get the frame that the playhead is on, then re-assemble those frames into animated gifs.